# Loading behaviour of referenced Entity in non-cacheable Entity

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

Entity `A` is marked as `@Cacheable(false)` and `A` holds a relationship to another entity class `B` which is cacheable by default.

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class A {
    // ...
    @xxxToOne B b;
}
```

What is going to happening, when I load an `A` instance through the EntityManager, when the related `B` instance is already available in the (2nd Level) cache? Will the framework perform the JOIN on the database and load the entire information of `B` as well, or will it return the `B` instance from the Cache?

Does the `FetchType` influence this behaviour?

Is this clearly defined in the JPA Spec. or may it depend on the JPA vendor?

Comment: i'd expect the B FK to be loaded from the database (since it has to when loading the A), but then look in the L2 cache for the B. What does your JPA vendor do?

Comment: As you said, it picks the already existing objects from the Cache. - There are tons of subsequent calls to the DB to get the B's which are not already in the Cache (no matter what FetchType I chose, or if I mark the relation explicitly with @JoinFetch), but this seems to be unrelated to the `@Caheable` so it's a different question.

Comment: EclipseLink will not by default join in a table unless you've told it to, regardless of the access type or caching - they are independent settings.  If the query is such that it is a primary key find operation, the cache can be used upfront avoiding the database.  Otherwise, it may query the database and use the cache on the way back, returning the object from the cache instead of having to rebuild it. Being in a transaction also plays apart in when the shared cache can be used, as transactional changes need to be isolated.